# Else is an invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I wrote some code that will download a webpage and then search for a certain string, i know this is an inefficient way to do it but it is the way i chose, anyways the code always comes up with an invalid syntax for else. Any help is welcome! code:

```
import requests
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter

#download website and turns into a .txt file
while true:
    print('Beginning file download with requests')
    url = str(input("Enter Profile ID:"))
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Notification/[profile.txt', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(r.content)

# Retrieve HTTP meta-data
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)
#opens text file and searches for a certain keyword
with open('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Notification/[profile.txt') as f:
    if 'avatar-status online profile-avatar-status icon-online' in f.read():#if it finds the keyword it sleeps and then retries
        time.sleep(20)
    continue
#if it doesnt find the keyword (meaning they are offline) it sends you a message through discord webhook
    else:
    webhook = Webhook.from_url("YOUR WEBHOOK HERE!", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
    webhook.send("Found string")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to capitalize `T` in `True`
- Your `continue` is outside of the `while` because it is not indented.
- Your `continue` is outside of the `if` because it is not indented, which then disconnects the `else` from the `if`
- Your `else` body is not indented

```
while True: # Capitalize
    print('Beginning file download with requests')
    url = str(input("Enter Profile ID:"))
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Notification/[profile.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

    # Indent everything below this
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.headers['content-type'])
    print(r.encoding)
    #opens text file and searches for a certain keyword
    with open('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Notification/[profile.txt') as f:
        if 'avatar-status online profile-avatar-status icon-online' in f.read():
            time.sleep(20)
            continue # indent this to align with the sleep
        else:
            webhook = Webhook.from_url("YOUR WEBHOOK HERE!", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter()) # indent this to be in the else
            webhook.send("Found string") # indent this too
```

To refine this further:

- you don't need that extra file at all, search `r.content` for a byte string
- `input()` returns `str()` so you don't need to convert it
- there's nothing after the `if`/`else`, so you don't need the `continue`

```
while True:
    print('Beginning file download with requests')
    url = input("Enter Profile ID:")
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.headers['content-type'])
    print(r.encoding)
    if b'avatar-status online profile-avatar-status icon-online' in r.content:
        time.sleep(20)
    else:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url("YOUR WEBHOOK HERE!", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
        webhook.send("Found string")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is continue. You cannot place any other code outside 'if' and then use else.

Answer (score -2):

Python uses indentation as syntax, so it can't associate the 'else' with an if statement.

Try indenting the 'continue' and the lines after 'else':

```
with open('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Notification/[profile.txt') as f:
    if 'avatar-status online profile-avatar-status icon-online' in f.read():#if it finds the keyword it sleeps and then retries
        time.sleep(20)
        continue
#if it doesnt find the keyword (meaning they are offline) it sends you a message through discord webhook
    else:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url("YOUR WEBHOOK HERE!", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
        webhook.send("Found string")
```

Comment: this is bad syntax. You'll get `continue outside of loop`. Neither with nor if are loop blocks.